# Extracting Slope & Intercept from a Scatterplot Trendline Programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I cannot seem to find a built in property for Excel Chart Trendlines where I can grab the slope or the intercept. It allows me to display the trendline equation on the chart itself in excel, but I can't access it within the code. Anyone know any property or method that I may have been overlooking? I can always calculate the equation separately, it just seems like a waste if Excel already has it, but I can't access it.

Comment: It can be done with formula on the excel sheet.

Comment: see: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/

Comment: I know I can do that in the excel spreadsheet itself, but I'm trying to work with it inside the code, so that the user doesn't have to calculate it manually.

Comment: is there not a line of code `applicationfunction` or the like that allows you to run excel formulas within ones code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kindof found what I was looking for. I would ideally like to extract the trendline directly from the Excel chart, but I found a way to access excel functions within the code. Forward Ed put me on the right track.

using IExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Then declare and initialise a IWorkSheetFunction object

IExcel.IWorksheetFunction iwf;

Now you can use the functions as in
   double result = iwf.NormDist(1,2,3,4);

Comment: My normal warning whenever I see Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in a question.  Don't run this code on a server (actually anywhere other than a user's workstation): See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but I'm only using this for a data analysis program to be run on a user's workstation.